# Spring RestTemplate getForObject contains duplicate headers after reusing it for multiple requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

at each of my usages. I initialized RestTemplate in my Application class as :

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000);
    httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(30 * 1000);

    return new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory);
}
```

Please suggest me the reason for this issue. Also correct me if I am proceeding wrong in anyway.

Comment: show some logs.

Comment: as far as I know `@Bean` creates a singleton

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution to avoid duplicate headers:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was in registering message converters in autowired resttemplate for each request utilizing this bean, therefore corrupting resttemplate bean for entire application. 
As each message converter provide its own "accept" capabilities, therefore it was duplicated for each request (this bug was fixed somewhere in spring 5.x, now only unique accept values been sent to server)

Answer (score -1):

try to change the @Bean with @Component and let me know if it works